# Como faço para encerrar o programa, fechando uma janela no forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um programa que abre diferentes forms.
Se eu fechar a janela do meu form "base", por exempro o "form1", o aplicativo se encerra normalmente. O meu problema é, se eu fechar a janela de um form aberto pelo form1, um "form2", o programa não se encerra. O meu objetivo é conseguir fechar o programa a partir de um form aberto pelo meu form "base".

Comment: Nos evento [`Form.OnFormClosed()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosed?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) desse `form2` encerre a aplicação usando o método [`Application.Exit()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).